# Extended Data Table and Modal Panel

Tags: richfaces

I have an rich faces extended data table the following data for rows,

added date, notes, user, change date and etc.

When the items are populated the user will be able to edit specific things such as notes field.

I have a commandButton with that notes field, and it pops up a rich faces modal panel, but for some reason my modal panel isn't retrieving the correct row. rather it always returns the first row of the extended data table

Any suggestions?

Heres the code for the specific columns, note it is over an a4j:form

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Edit Status Notes" rendered="#{selectedErrorInfo.errorId == errInfo.errorId}" 
                                         oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('statusNotesPanel', {width: 350, top: 150});" >


                                    </a4j:commandButton>
                                        <rich:modalPanel id="statusNotesPanel">                                     
                                            <center>
                                            <h:inputTextarea value="#{errInfo.statusNotes}" style="height:100px; width:300px;" maxlength="4000"/>
                                            <br/>                                           
                                            <a4j:commandButton value="Close" oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('statusNotesPanel');" />
                                            </center>                                           
                                        </rich:modalPanel>
```

**ANSWER**

Okay so couple of things.
First, the Modal panel CANNOT be in the original data table's form. Example of this is

```
<h:form>
 <rich:ExtendedDatatable>
  ...... info here (if there is any ModalPanel within this area with forms, it will not work
 </rich?:ExtendedDataTable>
</h:form>
```

so you need it outside the original form.

Second, you will need to reRender the modalPanel on open action. What I did is use a commandButton and set reRender = to the id of the modalPanel's form. ex:

```
<rich:commandButton reRender="blah"  oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('blah', {width: 350, top: 150});">

<rich:modalPanel id= "blah">
```

Third, I used a DataModelSelection to let ajax do all my selections.
You have to say in order to use it is

class.SelectedItem.property
so In example.

```
public class TestClass
{

 @DataModel
 List<Person> testItems;

 @DataModelSelection("testItems")
 Person selectedlistItem;
}

public class person
{

 String name;
 String lastName;

 //getters setters etc.
}
```

in XHTML you will need.

```
<rich:modalPanel>
<h:form>
 <h:inputText value="#{TestClass.selectedListItem.name}"/> in order to retrieve the name 
</h:form>
```

Comment: What is errInfo.statusNotes and selectedErrorInfo.errorId? Could you give more source code (datatable) ?

Comment: selectedErrorInfo is actually the DataModelSelection

Comment: and errInfo is just the var, that contains the information of the status notes

Comment: been googling, seems more or less like modal panel issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does your modalPanel declared in the iteration of the datatable ?

In this case (and I think so), the problem is all of your modalPanels have the same id (`statusNotesPanel`).
Try to concatenate `statusNotesPanel` and `errInfo.errorId` as the id of the rich:modalPanel.

Comment: If not declared in the datatable, Could you give more source code please?

Comment: sorry, i'm still trying to figure out some sort of way to fix this. I'm going to try a couple of more things. I feel like i'm close.

Comment: Okay I figured it out. i'll post answer inside the edit. Thanks so much jean!